# Where are my bitcoins after wallet removal

Tags: blockchain, wallet, multibit

I'm a newbee with bitcoins, but there is something I don't understand.

I've downloaded MultiBit, but with this I was not able to see anything on my iPhone. So I also openend a wallet on Blockchain. I transferred the money from MultiBit to Blockchain and this al went well.

Secondly I removed my wallet in MultiBit and now my Blockchain wallet is also empty... How is that possible?

This is my last transfer... https://blockchain.info/nl/tx/b9a85a99f168f9e8fcd5b1385868cdbfc8bcb4f4205e65499bd13a27fc024d95

Comment: It appears that the transaction is valid and the output was not spent. Are you sure that you are logged into the same Blockchain wallet and that you sent it to the correct address? You may want to contact Blockchain for resolution.

Answer (score 1):

These two events

- removing your wallet from Multibit
- observing zero balance in your Blockchain.info wallet

are extremely unlikely to be related. You can see that the transaction went through and has several dozen confirmations.

If your Blockchain.info wallet is appearing empty, you may want to contact Blockchain.info for resolution.